# How to restore purchases on a second device (INAPP and SUBS)

Tags: android, android-billing, billingclient

I have the following situation:

A user purchases a subscription on an app on his **device A**. Later on, he buys a **device B** and configures it with the same account of **device A**. He installs that same app on **device B**, but the purchase he made on **device A** is not available there.

What can I do to make **device B** recognize the purchase? I tried using [BillingClient#purchaseHistoryResponseListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(java.lang.String,%20com.android.billingclient.api.PurchaseHistoryResponseListener)), but even though it really returns the most recent purchases, it is not possible to say if the purchase is active (if it as a SUBS) or if it is not consumed yet (if it is a INAPP).

Answer (score 8):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you will have this information in [queryPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases). As you already must know, this takes information from cache. So from device B you first need to make the [queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchasehistoryasync) call, this refreshes the cache if this call is successful, and once it is, you can get the information you need in [queryPurchases()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#querypurchases).

It has not been mentioned in the documentation that this method refreshes the cache, but this trick does seem to work for me and a bunch others if you refer [here](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/139)

Comment: This issue thread has a different story https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/122 
Wonder what is going wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is a much needed bit of detail to know that queryPurchases() is refreshed from queryPurchaseHistoryAsync().