# Using Android BillingClient, how to restore a user's IAP after re-installing, or changing their device?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, restore, android-billing

My application has a single one-time non-consumable IAP to turn off advertisement.  I'm trying to provide a "Restore Purchase" option for my application. In the event a user uninstalls the application or migrates to a new device, they have an option to recover their one-time past purchase.

My app is following the purchase flow described within Google's documentation https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

I've looked for examples to restore a past purchase for a different device, but all the examples I've found are out dated referencing the AIDL methods.

I've looked at methods, `BillingClient.queryPurchases()` and `BillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()`. `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()` give a list of `PurchaseHistoryRecord`s, for all past purchases including canceled purchases, but does not provide the purchase status to determine if any of those are a completed or pending purchase.

In contrast, `queryPurchases()` will give a list of purchases and their status, but only for the device. It returns an empty list if a user made the IAP on a different device.

I do not have a backend as I'm an independent developer with limited resources, so my app must be self-contained.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I learned that `queryPurchases()` is cached locally on your device, but is updated when you call `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()`

I discovered from this Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60991072/612697)

So my solution, is when wanting to restore a purchase on a new device, or a fresh install of my app.  Call `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync()`  Then in the callback of `onPurchaseHistoryResponse()` call `queryPurchases()` and look within the `List<Purchase>` from the `PurchasesResult` for the purchase status of any of the user's past purchases.

If there's an expected purchase your app can grant the entitlements of their past purchase.

Comment: Is there any way to grant the entitlements from their previous purchases maybe from the device they may have used before or if they uninstall and install the application (The purchase being consumed or acknowledged before) ?

Answer (score 0):

Purchases are linked to the device Google account, if the user installs the app and uses the same account on the second device then `BillingClient.queryPurchases()` will return that he owns the purchased IAP

If he wants to use a different Google account then he will have to buy the item again.

Comment: The problem with using BillingClient.queryPurchases() is that it uses the local cache of that device.  So if the user gets a newer device, that local cache is empty and queryPurchases() will not provide the IAP from the other device.